# Sequelize JS - How to do multiple join query with composite key?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, associations, sequelize.js

I'm new in Sequelize and i've been wasting hours for just a simple query. The association of sequelize make my head spinning @@.

So I want to run this query

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, b.host_id FROM RoomDetails a
          LEFT JOIN Rooms b ON b.host_id = a.chat_id
          LEFT JOIN States c ON c.id = b.state_id
          WHERE c.bot='$bot_name' AND c.chat_id='$chatid';
```

I don't know how to achieve that way in sequelize format.
Here's my model:

**states.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var states = sequelize.define('states', {
    botName: DataTypes.STRING,
    chatId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    state: DataTypes.STRING,
    turnId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    turnName: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        states.hasOne(models.rooms, {
          as: 'rooms',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'stateId'
          },
          foreignKeyConstraint: true
        });
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return states;
};
```

**rooms.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var rooms = sequelize.define('rooms', {
    stateId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    hostId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    maxLetter: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        rooms.belongsTo(models.states, {
          as: 'states',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'stateId'
          },
          foreignKeyConstraint: true
        });
        rooms.hasMany(models.roomdetails, {
          as: 'roomdetails',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'roomId'
          },
          foreignKeyConstraint: true
        });
        rooms.belongsToMany(models.roomdetails, {
          as: 'roomdetailschatid',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'hostId'
          },
          foreignKeyConstraint: true
        });
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return rooms;
};
```

**roomdetails.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var roomdetails = sequelize.define('roomdetails', {
    roomId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    chatId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        roomdetails.belongsTo(models.rooms, {
          as: 'rooms',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'roomId'
          },
          foreignKeyConstraint: true
        });
        roomdetails.belongsTo(models.rooms, {
          as: 'roomshostid',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'chatId'
          },
          foreignKeyConstraint: true
        });
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return roomdetails;
};
```

This is what i've been trying so far

```
module.exports.getHostInfo = function(res) {
    return models.roomdetails.findOne({
        include: {
            required: true,
            model: models.rooms,
            as: 'rooms',
            include: {
                required: true,
                model: models.states,
                as: 'states',
                where: {
                    botName: { $eq: general.botName },
                    chatId: { $eq: res.chat.id },
                    state: { $ne: general.FINISHED}
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error getTotalPlayer', error);
    });
}
```

and it always return error like **unknown columns 'rooms.roomdetailId' in 'field list'**

Any body can help me ?
Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, Sequelize can't find columns with camelCase while in database columns were saved using snake_case. Try to define foreignKeys using snake_case:

```
    rooms.hasMany(models.roomdetails, {
      as: 'roomdetails',
      foreignKey: 'room_id',
      foreignKeyConstraint: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you defines associations in models/index.js? If not define like below

```
sequelize.roomDetails.belongsTo(sequelize.roome);
sequelize.rooms.hasMany(sequelize.roomDetails, {as: 'roomDetails', foreignKey: 'room_id'});
```

then you can use

```
rooms.hasMany(models.roomdetails, {
  as: 'roomdetails',
  foreignKey: 'room_id',
  foreignKeyConstraint: true
});
```

Hope this will help you !